# How to get modifyable values from nim Tables

Tags: nim-lang

I'm totally new to Nim, and am trying to modify values in a table. Specifically, I'd like to append items to a sequence stored as a value in a table. My current code looks like:

```
import tables

var table = initTable[string, seq[string]]()
table["a"] = @["foo"]
var x = table["a"]
x.add("bar")

echo $table
```

The table entry "a" just contains ["foo"] and not ["foo", "bar"], which I'm guessing is because accessing table["a"] is returning a copy of the sequence that was originally inserted. How do I access (a reference to) the original seq, and not a copy?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is on the line:

```
var x = table["a"]
```

This actually makes a copy of what's stored in `table["a"]`. Because seqs are pass-by-copy, this copies all the data stored in the seq into a new seq stored in `x`. If you want a reference to the seq stored in the table, you have two options:

- the safer option, just modify the value directly. `tables.[]` returns a `var T` for all `var Table`s:

```
table["a"].add("bar")
```

- the unsafe option, take a pointer to that value and modify that

```
var x = addr table["a"]
x[].add("bar")
```

However I would advise against using pointers unless you're absolutely sure you know what you're doing. There's also an experimental feature: view types. However, it's not yet stable and even this simple example fails with a SIGSEGV (as of 1.4.2):

```
var x: var seq[string] = table["a"]
x.add("bar")
```

Comment: Also, depending on what you need to do, you can use mvalues, mpairs or mGetOrPut.

Comment: Thanks! This totally works. Confusing how seqs are heap-allocated but apparently have value (not reference) semantics.